# Does resurrecting allies prevent the durability penalty for dying?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just learned from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67753/how-do-you-resurrect-allies) that it's possible to resurrect allies. We also know from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66244/what-happens-when-you-die) that the penalty for dying is a 10% degradation in durability.

If you revive/resurrect an ally, is the durability penalty prevented?

Comment: @bwarner You're right, I changed the body text to be consistent. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You take the durability hit when you die. It doesn't matter how you are returned to life.

[image]

Comment: Found this screenshot online, so it may be from beta. I'll post my own screenshot _if I ever die._ \*evil cackle\* (my wife has died, that's how I know the answer to this question) (aww, that was a sad thing to write)

Comment: It still looks basically the same.

Answer (score 3):

**No**.  You gain the durability penalty immediately once you die.

So if you are in a boss fight and you die again and again and again but get a revive every time, eventually your equipment will break ( 0 / X durability )